How to identify nth row that satisfies condition
I have a dataframe with months and sales. If somebody does 250 sales for 3 consecutive months, they get a bonus.

Once the bonus month is identified, the counter resets and starts to count the next 3 consecutive months with 250
if there is less than 250 sales, then the counter resets




Month
sales
3 month consistency




Month 1
250



Month 2
250



Month 3
250
1


Month 4
250



Month 5
250



Month 6
250
1


Month 7
0



Month 8
250



Month 9
250



Month 10
250
1


Month 11
250



Month 12
250



Month 13
0



Month 14
250



Month 15
250



Month 16
250
1



I want to populate the 3 month consistency column
Tried using cum count with conditions but it did not work and I could not find such an example anywhere. What I tried was to use rolling window to identify every 3rd consecutive record with 250. But then it does not reset after the each set of 3 consecutive 250s.
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['gt_250'].rolling(min_periods=1, window=3).sum())
#-- grouped by id because this has to be computed for each salesperson_id

The result I got from it was,



Month
sales
3 month consistency




Month 1
250



Month 2
250



Month 3
250
3


Month 4
250
3


Month 5
250
3




What did you try? Please show your code. That can give us somewhere to start. For related tips, see How to make good reproducible pandas examples

@wjandrea - updated :)

You could use a custom groupby.cumcount and mod:
N = 3 # number of consecutive months

# identify target months
m = df['sales'].ge(250)
# for groups of consecutive target months
group = (~m).cumsum()

# count the Nth repeat for each group
df['3 month consistency'] = (df[m].groupby(group).cumcount().mod(N).eq(N-1)
                             .map({True: 1})
                            )

NB. if you want a boolean column replace .map({True: 1}) by .reindex(df.index).eq(True).
Output:
       Month  sales  3 month consistency
0    Month 1    250                  NaN
1    Month 2    250                  NaN
2    Month 3    250                  1.0
3    Month 4    250                  NaN
4    Month 5    250                  NaN
5    Month 6    250                  1.0
6    Month 7      0                  NaN
7    Month 8    250                  NaN
8    Month 9    250                  NaN
9   Month 10    250                  1.0
10  Month 11    250                  NaN
11  Month 12    250                  NaN
12  Month 13      0                  NaN
13  Month 14    250                  NaN
14  Month 15    250                  NaN
15  Month 16    250                  1.0

Intermediates:
       Month  sales      m  group  cumcount  mod  3 month consistency
0    Month 1    250   True      0       0.0  0.0                  NaN
1    Month 2    250   True      0       1.0  1.0                  NaN
2    Month 3    250   True      0       2.0  2.0                  1.0
3    Month 4    250   True      0       3.0  0.0                  NaN
4    Month 5    250   True      0       4.0  1.0                  NaN
5    Month 6    250   True      0       5.0  2.0                  1.0
6    Month 7      0  False      1       NaN  NaN                  NaN
7    Month 8    250   True      1       0.0  0.0                  NaN
8    Month 9    250   True      1       1.0  1.0                  NaN
9   Month 10    250   True      1       2.0  2.0                  1.0
10  Month 11    250   True      1       3.0  0.0                  NaN
11  Month 12    250   True      1       4.0  1.0                  NaN
12  Month 13      0  False      2       NaN  NaN                  NaN
13  Month 14    250   True      2       0.0  0.0                  NaN
14  Month 15    250   True      2       1.0  1.0                  NaN
15  Month 16    250   True      2       2.0  2.0                  1.0

Variant (with a boolean output):
N = 3
m = df['sales'].ge(250)
group = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()
df['3 month consistency'] = df.groupby(group).cumcount().mod(N).eq(N-1)

Intermediates:
       Month  sales      m  group  cumcount  mod  3 month consistency
0    Month 1    250   True      1         0    0                False
1    Month 2    250   True      1         1    1                False
2    Month 3    250   True      1         2    2                 True
3    Month 4    250   True      1         3    0                False
4    Month 5    250   True      1         4    1                False
5    Month 6    250   True      1         5    2                 True
6    Month 7      0  False      2         0    0                False
7    Month 8    250   True      3         0    0                False
8    Month 9    250   True      3         1    1                False
9   Month 10    250   True      3         2    2                 True
10  Month 11    250   True      3         3    0                False
11  Month 12    250   True      3         4    1                False
12  Month 13      0  False      4         0    0                False
13  Month 14    250   True      5         0    0                False
14  Month 15    250   True      5         1    1                False
15  Month 16    250   True      5         2    2                 True

per ID
N = 3
m = df['sales'].ge(250)
group = m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()
df['3 month consistency'] = df.groupby(['ID', group]).cumcount().mod(N).eq(N-1)

Example:
   ID     Month  sales  3 month consistency
0   A   Month 1    250                False
1   A   Month 2    250                False
2   A   Month 3    250                 True
3   A   Month 4    250                False
4   A   Month 5    250                False
5   A   Month 6    250                 True
6   A   Month 7      0                False
7   A   Month 8    250                False
8   A   Month 9    250                False
9   A  Month 10    250                 True
10  A  Month 11    250                False
11  A  Month 12    250                False
12  A  Month 13      0                False
13  A  Month 14    250                False
14  A  Month 15    250                False
15  B   Month 1    250                False  # independent from A
16  B   Month 2    250                False
17  B   Month 3    250                 True
18  B   Month 4    250                False
19  B   Month 5    250                False
20  B   Month 6    250                 True
21  B   Month 7      0                False
22  B   Month 8    250                False
23  B   Month 9    250                False
24  B  Month 10    250                 True
25  B  Month 11    250                False
26  B  Month 12    250                False
27  B  Month 13      0                False
28  B  Month 14    250                False
29  B  Month 15    250                False


this works. If I want to do the same for each id separately (i.e.) assume there is an ID column in the table, how can I accomplish that pls.

Also group by ID in addition to group (.groupby(['ID', group])).

Works like a charm! Thanks so much!
Appreciate adding the intermediate results too - it help understand the solution!

A possible solution, which uses list comprehension:
N = 3
threshold = 250

counter = 0

df['res'] = [
    (counter := 0, np.nan)[1] if sales < threshold else (
        (counter := counter + 1) == N and (counter := 0, 1.0)[1] or np.nan
    )
    for sales in df['sales']
]

Output:
       Month  sales  3 month consistency  res
0    Month 1    250                  NaN  NaN
1    Month 2    250                  NaN  NaN
2    Month 3    250                  1.0  1.0
3    Month 4    250                  NaN  NaN
4    Month 5    250                  NaN  NaN
5    Month 6    250                  1.0  1.0
6    Month 7      0                  NaN  NaN
7    Month 8    250                  NaN  NaN
8    Month 9    250                  NaN  NaN
9   Month 10    250                  1.0  1.0
10  Month 11    250                  NaN  NaN
11  Month 12    250                  NaN  NaN
12  Month 13      0                  NaN  NaN
13  Month 14    250                  NaN  NaN
14  Month 15    250                  NaN  NaN
15  Month 16    250                  1.0  1.0


The walrus doesn't help where you're writing it only to ignore the expression ((counter := 0, ...)[1]). You should use a plain for-loop instead; it'd be more readable.

Thanks, @wjandrea, for your comment. I guess it is a question of taste, really -- I personally prefer the way I did. However, you may consider to post a solution with a plain for-loop -- I do not have time to do so.
